# How to make only the user who saved the String can see Flutter / Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

This is a code that saves a String of qr code that is not repeated in the database, but this way everyone can access this data, I already got the user Id but still could not filter to just see the list.

```
void SalvarMensagem() async {

  String uid = UserModel.of(context).firebaseUser.uid;

  this._status = _status;
  _numeroSerie = _status.substring(48, 80);

  final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
      .collection("lockers")
      .where("numero_serie", isEqualTo: "$_numeroSerie")
      .limit(1)
      .getDocuments());

  final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
  if (documents.length == 1) {
   // duplicado(context);
  } else {
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection("lockers")
        .document()
        .setData({"numero_serie": _numeroSerie, "userId": uid});
  }
}
```

firebase:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to get the created's ID's user file, but you can create a attribute on your document with the user's UID and when you want read the docs you can filter by query like `where("user_created_uid","===",uid)`.